How to fix macOS 15 tab location with backward compatibility
I have a view at the top level of my scene that contains a TabView(). The TabView() itself is inside an HStack. With macOS 15, this situation results in the tabs themselves showing up in the app's title bar, replacing the app name. This is not appropriate for my app so I want to get the tabs back to where they were before macOS 15.
Apple has provided a tabViewStyle(.grouped) to accomplish this. The problem, though, is that my app needs to be backwards compatible to macOS 13 and tabViewStyle(.grouped) is not available before macOS 15.
I have tried to put the modifier inside of an if #available(macOS 15, *) conditional but the compiler then complains "Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'grouped'"
I could put the entire TabView() inside of a conditional but there's a fair amount of code that would be repeated, leading to code maintenance issues.
I'm stuck. How do I get the tabs where I want them in macOS 15 while maintaining backward compatibility to macOS 13?
